# How do I prevent permission escalation in Django admin when granting "user change" permission?

Tags: django, permissions, django-admin, django-users

I have a django site with a large customer base. I would like to give our customer service department the ability to alter normal user accounts, doing things like changing passwords, email addresses, etc. However, if I grant someone the built-in `auth | user | Can change user` permission, they gain the ability to set the `is_superuser` flag on any account, including their own. (!!!)

What's the best way to remove this option for non-superuser staff? I'm sure it involves subclassing `django.contrib.auth.forms.UserChangeForm` and hooking it into my already-custom `UserAdmin` object... somehow. But I can't find any documentation on how to do this, and I don't yet understand the internals well enough.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> they gain the ability to set the is_superuser flag on any account, including their own. (!!!)

Not only this, they also gain the ability to give themselves any permissions one-by-one, same effect...

> I'm sure it involves subclassing django.contrib.auth.forms.UserChangeForm

Well, not necessarily. The form you see in the change page of django's admin is dynamically created by the admin application, and based on `UserChangeForm`, but this class barely adds regex validation to the `username` field.

> and hooking it into my already-custom UserAdmin object...

A custom `UserAdmin` is the way to go here. Basically, you want to change the `fieldsets` property to something like that :

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        # Removing the permission part
        # (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
        # Keeping the group parts? Ok, but they shouldn't be able to define
        # their own groups, up to you...
        (_('Groups'), {'fields': ('groups',)}),
    )
```

But the problem here is that this restriction will apply to all users. If this is not what you want, you could for example override `change_view` to behave differently depending on the permission of the users. Code snippet :

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    staff_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        # No permissions
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
        (_('Groups'), {'fields': ('groups',)}),
    )

    def change_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # for non-superuser
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            try:
                self.fieldsets = self.staff_fieldsets
                response = super(MyUserAdmin, self).change_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                # Reset fieldsets to its original value
                self.fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets
            return response
        else:
            return super(MyUserAdmin, self).change_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Since I'm using Groups to manage permissions, I also removed the Groups section from `staff_fieldsets`.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot! However, Django 1.1.2 didn't seem to like the '_' you had before Personal info and the rest.

Comment: @Tyug : the `_` is the usual import alias for `ugettext` / `ugettext_lazy`, as you can see in code examples on http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/internationalization/ : `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _`

Comment: The non-superuser is still able to change a superusers' password and log in with her account. To disallow this, I removed the password field as well from the `staff_fieldsets`, wrote a wrapper around `UserAdmin.user_change_password` that disallows changing the password of superusers for non-superusers, and finally added a link to `"password/"` in the first fieldsets' `description`.

Comment: Hiding the fields is not sufficient. An user with sufficient web develpment knowledge will be able to craft his own POST requests at the appropriate url by using wget.

Comment: @DavidEyk and Clément can I show the super user checkbox while adding new user ? is it possible ?

Comment: This doesnt work anymore.  I am on Django 1.7 so maybe something has changed.  
File "/home/vivekv/.environments/timetracker/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in clean_password
  154.         return self.initial["password"]

Exception Type: KeyError at /admin/auth/user/2/
Exception Value: u'password'

Answer (score 9):

The below part of the accepted answer has a race condition where if two staff users try to access the admin form at the same time, one of them may get the superuser form.

> ```
> try:
>     self.readonly_fields = self.staff_self_readonly_fields
>     response = super(MyUserAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context, *args, **kwargs)
> finally:
>     # Reset fieldsets to its original value
>     self.fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets
> ```

To avoid this race condition (and in my opinion improve the overall quality of the solution), we can override the `get_fieldsets()` and `get_readonly_fields()` methods directly:

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    staff_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        # No permissions
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    staff_readonly_fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'last_login', 'date_joined')

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.staff_fieldsets
        else:
            return super(UserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.staff_readonly_fields
        else:
            return super(UserAdmin, self).get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Great thanks to Clément. What I came up with when doing the same for my site is that I needed additionally to make all fields readonly for users you other than self. So basing on Clément's answer I addeed readonly fields and password field hiding when viewing not self

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User
    staff_self_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        # No permissions
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )

    staff_other_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', )}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        # No permissions
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )

    staff_self_readonly_fields = ('last_login', 'date_joined')

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # for non-superuser
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            try:
                if int(object_id) != request.user.id:
                    self.readonly_fields = User._meta.get_all_field_names()
                    self.fieldsets = self.staff_other_fieldsets
                else:
                    self.readonly_fields = self.staff_self_readonly_fields
                    self.fieldsets = self.staff_self_fieldsets

                response = super(MyUserAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context, *args, **kwargs)
            except:
                logger.error('Admin change view error. Returned all readonly fields')

                self.fieldsets = self.staff_other_fieldsets
                self.readonly_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'last_login', 'date_joined')
                response = super(MyUserAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context, *args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                # Reset fieldsets to its original value
                self.fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets
                self.readonly_fields = UserAdmin.readonly_fields
            return response
        else:
            return super(MyUserAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach was put together from several helpful tips on the web. In this case we are modifying UserAdmin so that, for non-superuser staff with user add/change permission, the only permissions and groups they can grant another user are the ones the staff member already has.

(for Django 1.11)

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin, User
from django.contrib import admin

class RestrictedUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        field = super(RestrictedUserAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
        user = kwargs['request'].user
        if not user.is_superuser:
            if db_field.name == 'groups':
                field.queryset = field.queryset.filter(id__in=[i.id for i in user.groups.all()])
            if db_field.name == 'user_permissions':
                field.queryset = field.queryset.filter(id__in=[i.id for i in user.user_permissions.all()])
            if db_field.name == 'is_superuser':
                field.widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
        return field

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, RestrictedUserAdmin)
```

This should likewise be done for GroupAdmin if a user is given permission to change groups.

Answer (score 0):

Full code for django 1.1 (limited to basic user information for staff (not superusers))

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
   my_fieldsets = (
       (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
       (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
   )

   def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
       # for non-superuser
       print 'test'
       if not request.user.is_superuser:
           self.fieldsets = self.my_fieldsets
           response = UserAdmin.change_view(self, request, object_id,
extra_context=None)
           return response
       else:
           return UserAdmin.change_view(self, request, object_id,
extra_context=None)


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```